# Using a list against an input and seeing if it contains anything within a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Currently trying to find if an input contains anything within a list using python. I'm building a Discord Bot with rewrite, and want it to look at a message's content, and see if anything within is found in a list. I currently have it responding to messages that are equivalent to and item in the list, but I want it to respond to a message, for example that says "Hello world", not just "Hello".

```
greetings = ['hi', 'hello', 'bonjour', 'hola', 'hey', 'howdy', 'sup', 'welcome', 'greetings', 'yo', 'yoo', 'suh',
'hey there', 'hey y\'all', 'what\'s up', 'whats up', 'whatsup', 'wassup', 'sup?', 'what\'s shakin\'', 'what\'s new?',
'long time no see', 'good evening', 'good afternoon']


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
    content = message.content.lower()
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if content in greetings:
            await message.channel.send('Hello.')
            return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking if a whole string is in a list, e.g:

```py
>>> content = "hey whatever 123"
>>> greetings = ["hey", "hi"]
>>> 
>>> content in greetings
False
```

You should use the `any` function to check if the message contains any greeting

```py
>>> content = "hey whatever 123"
>>> greetings = ["hey", "hi"]
>>> 
>>> any(greeting in content for greeting in greetings)
True
```

Applied to your code

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    content = message.content.lower()

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if any(greeting in content for greeting in greetings):
        return await message.channel.send('Hello.')

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if each keyword is in your content, not if your content is in the list of keywords.

```
for key_word in greetings:
  if key_word in content:
    await message.channel.send(f"Greeting {key_word} found!")
    return
```

Using the `any` function makes this a lot simpler if you don't care about which greeting was found.